# Delete group of markers by its id in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, marker

I have multiple markers that move when their location changes, lets say I have 20 markers and I want 10 to be in a group and the other 10 to be in another group and the user needs to hide only the first group of markers, is this possible? I was thinking of storing the markers in a hashmap but I dont know if its possible to toggle the visibility of a group of markers by just getting its ID.
What would be a good approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could storage the markers in a simple `ArrayList<Marker>` another alternative is storage them in a `HashMap<int,Marker>` Where `int` is the id.

Comment: thanks Silmood, I think that i'll add the markers from a group to an array and then add that array to the hashmap.

Comment: You are welcome :) tell me if you have another problem with that.